# MySQL query with avg and count greater than a value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table *tbl_emply* containing fields *Salary*, *DNO*, and *EID* for each employ. I need to find average *Salary* of each *DNO* that has more than two employees.

[image: Table Contents]

I have tried queries like

1. ```
   select avg(salary),DNO 
   from tbl_emply 
   where count(select * from tbl_emply group by(DNO)>2);
   ```
2. ```
   select avg(salary),DNO 
   from tbl_emply 
   group by(DNO);
   ```

But these all gave me invalid use of group by. How to get the result?

Answer (score 6):

Use `HAVING`

```
SELECT AVG(salary), DNO
FROM tbl_emply
GROUP BY DNO
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select avg(Salary),DNo from tbl_emply group by DNo having count(*)>2;
```